# Toolbar overflow in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a toolbar defined as "toolBar" property of a ApplicationWindow.
When I resize the window I want that toolBar (if it's too large for the current size) handle overflow with a "more" item. After a lot of research I couldn't found anything on the web. I join some screenshot of what I have and what I want.

[image]

[image]

The second example is something I have done in pure C++.

In my research I also read something about toolbar only handle overflow in MainWindow and that maybe why I can't make it work in ApplicationWindow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing like this exists in Qt Quick Controls. I played around with something similar a while back, but wasn't happy with it: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/166325/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done if you go for a model driven toolbar items.

Then, if the toolbar view is not wide enough to fit everything, you can calculate the index it cuts out at, and implement a drop down menu with another view, this time vertical, that shows only items after the cutout index.

It is not ideal, but since there is no built in support for that, this is by far the easiest and quickest way to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'll try it. The driven model is reloaded each time the view is resized ?

Comment: That's how it is done in the Fluid library : https://github.com/lirios/fluid/blob/v1.0.0/src/imports/controls/AppBar.qml#L171-L267

Comment: No it is not reloaded. The goal here is to be able to have the same items in both the toolbar and the overflow menu.

Comment: @GrecKo that solution seems to be fixed width. By using something like ListView's `indexAt(x, y)` it would be possible to make it work with varying width items too.